# Where has .btn-default gone in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

According to the Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 migration docs:

> Buttons
>
> - Renamed .btn-default to .btn-secondary.

But the Bootstrap 4 [`.btn-secondary`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#examples) does not look at all like the [old default button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons-options).

#### Bootstrap 3:

[image: bootstrap 3 default button]

#### Bootstrap 4:

[image: bootstrap 4 primary secondary light]

Using `.btn-light` does not reproduce the original `.btn-default` either.

How do I get my default theme back for buttons/dropdowns, etc?

I remember a default button in Bootstrap 4, but it was in an earlier alpha version. Has it been removed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `btn-outline-secondary` class in Bootstrap 4 generates the closest to what used to be `btn-default` in Bootstrap 3.

That seems to be "typo" there in the docs.

`primary` is the blue button/color and `secondary` is the grey ones.

And the very light grey is `btn-light`.

Here's the reference link for Bootstrap 4 buttons:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Comment: the btn-secondary is dark grey on my side. I want the former light-white, any idea? I know of course the button link, but they do not offer that former white...

Comment: That is literally `btn-light`.

Comment: Have a look at the link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp I mean the default button. and now compare that default button to the light https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ its NOT the same look. I do not care about the names of course... I care about the look/style.

Comment: Aha, that one. The closest to that is `btn-outline-secondary`.

Comment: And if you wanted it to look **precisely** the same, then you could use `btn-outline-secondary` as a basis and customize it a bit.

Comment: no... the closest is btn-outline-light , but then I can not read the text HAHA....prolly I gotta do that. Have a look at the light button here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/?#outline-buttons does NOT make sense at all as it can not be read...

Comment: Yeah, there is no exact match in Bootstrap 4 for that particular Bootstrap 3 style. But can be customized easily.

Comment: yes I hoped someone has done that before for me ;-) look here is the bs4 alpha version: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/ the default button is correct and nice :-) cool I can copy/paste it :P

Comment: That's where that migration notice comes from. Well, almost everything has changed since that old alpha version.

Answer (score 12):

add this css to your stylesheet file problem gone

```
.btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-default:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
.btn-default:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
.btn-default:active {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another "fix" is to define `default` as theme color in your SCSS files:

```
$theme-colors: ( "default": lightgray, "primary": ...)
```

Then `.btn-default` (and the other "default" classes) are back.

Answer (score 0):

At Bootstrap 5.3 you can simply:

```
.btn-default {
    --bs-btn-font-weight: 400;
    --bs-btn-color: #333;
    --bs-btn-bg: #fff;
    --bs-btn-border-color: #ccc;
    --bs-btn-hover-color: #333;
    --bs-btn-hover-bg: #e6e6e6;
    --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #adadad;
    --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: #8c8c8c;
    --bs-btn-active-color: #333;
    --bs-btn-active-bg: #d4d4d4;
    --bs-btn-active-border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
```